# MySQL Database not connecting to Android app

Tags: java, php, mysql, eclipse, android-studio

My database is running fine because I tested it using Eclipse with simple Java code that just connects and reports back success or fail. I connect fine....I can even read and write to it there.

Now, when I try to do the same thing in Android Studio,the connection fails. I am on the same WiFi network.

I created a lib folder for the app and put all the extra .jar files there including the JDBC connector for MySQL that I used in Eclipse. I also went to the build.gradel file and added the line:

```
compile files('libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar')
```

Do I need to make a PHP API for it to connect since right now I am trying to connect to it using this line:

```
 connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:port/testdb", "user", "password");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What, if any, errors are you getting?

Comment: It compiles cleanly. I inserted a line to print out the connection status and it prints "connection failed".

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't you should declare your permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`.

Then you may want to use something like JSON to make database requests from PHP.

Comment: I was wondering if there is an easier way since I am still trying to get it running on my Local network. I guess not.

Comment: @Jonathan you should not access your database directly like this, you should expose your data through a script, you can use JSON for that

Comment: Try SQLite if your database will be small enough and you don't mind having storing it on the device.

Comment: @AhmedDaou I considered using SQLite, but the app will share a database that is also used by a website. And the data might be a little too big. I might just go ahead and use JSON.

Comment: Excuse my butting in here, but you're best to build a PHP api that your android app can query to retrieve json with the data you require.

Comment: @Darren Yeah, that seems to be the best way to approach it, and I was going to implement it later on once I have the android stuff to work on a local network. Thanks. I will go ahead and get started on that.

Comment: @Jonathan No worries man, It's best to set up your API and build the app off that. Save yourself in the long run :)

Comment: @Darren Better take care of it now than taking the backfire of laziness later on :)